# How to convert the return result from a Task?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, delegates, task

I would like to execute an Action in a Queue using Task.Run and get the return value from the Action, and if successful, remove them from the queue.  All the actions in the Queue return type `Task<bool>`.  When the code is executed, the Action is executed successfully but then the Task.Run ultimately fails with:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Boolean]'.

The update method below is called from a base class as a Task:

```
public void Init()
{
    InitDaemon();

    KeepAliveTask = new Task(Run);
    KeepAliveTask.Start();
}

private void Run()
    while(_keepAlive)
    {  
        Update();
        Thread.Sleep(_updateMillSecs);
    }
}
```

_keepAlive is set to false when a base class Close() method is called.

```
void override Update()
{
    private static Task<bool> _currentTask;
    private static Queue<Action> _oisQueue = new Queue<Action>();

    // if there is at least one task in the queue and that task is complete
    if (_oisQueue.Count > 0 && (_currentTask == null || _currentTask.IsCompleted))
    {
        var action = _oisQueue.First();
        _currentTask = (Task<bool>)Task.Run(() => action());

        // if task was successful
        if (_currentTask.Result)
            _oisQueue.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Action`s don't have return values, use `Func<bool>` instead. Although it's not clear what you gain from using `Task.Run` if you immediately block waiting for the task to complete.

Comment: The action is asynchronous.

Comment: @Will "The action is asynchronous" is even more confusing reason to synchronously wait immediately after `Task.Run`...

Comment: I think what @Will is missing is that he doesn't realize `Task.Result` blocks. Will, `_currentTask.Result` blocks.

Comment: The action is a update to another computer.  Therefore it's an asynchronous call.  However in this method I need to block until I receive the return value, which will tell me whether the update is successful or not.

Comment: As noted above, you can get the `Result` property value, and the property getter will block until the `Task` completes. However, the _right_ way to do it is to `await` asynchronously. But there's not enough detail in your question for anyone to show you how to do that, beyond providing the same information that's already present in generous amounts on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  However I don't think using await is an option here. I'll try to add some more information on how this method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
class Class1
{
    private static Queue<Func<bool>> _oisQueue = new Queue<Func<bool>>();

    private async Task<bool> RunNextTask()
    {
        bool success = true;

        if (_oisQueue.Any())
        {
            success = await Task.Run(_oisQueue.First());
            _oisQueue.Dequeue();
        }

        return success;
    }
}
```